# Jenkins+Android+Cordova+Angular project deployment to multiple environment

Tags: android, cordova, jenkins

I am developing a hybrid app for android using Angular JS and cordova.
For build deployment, our organization is using Jenkins.
Now my issue is that through jenkins, I am building only the Android project folder inside the cordova project to generate the APK file.
I want to generate APK for different environemnts like Stage,Dev and Production by just changing a single property file.
How could the cordova+Angular project read the environment specific informations from a common file in Jenkins,also how to switch between different 
build enviromnments in Jenkins.
Could anyone suggest the thoughts .I am still confused in finding a solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you have code for different environments in different branches. Then you can parametrize branch name for github plugin in this job.

Comment: In your angular project you can use environment variables. In your src/environments folder you can create multiple environments. Here is a description: https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be